# Spyder 2 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, linux, spyder, ubuntu-18.04

How can I install spyder 2 in Ubuntu 18.04?

When I type this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install spyder
```

it installs spyder 3.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming you want `spyder2` for Python 2.7:**

You need to install `spyder` for the Python version you want:

```
python -m pip install spyder
```

Then you just need to run it for that version.  So:

```
python -m spyder
```

Comment: Note:  I have never actually tested this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pip to install it like follows

```
sudo pip install -Iv spyder==2.3.9
```

- `-I`: reinstall (Ignore installed).
- `v`: verbose.

https://pypi.org/project/spyder/

https://pypi.org/project/spyder/2.3.9/

Comment: Yes except in your link spyder is 3.2.8

Comment: You can use the realese history page to get to https://pypi.org/project/spyder/2.3.9/